# using VLOOKUP from Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've been making some great progress using VBA in Excel and Outlook lately but this topic has me stumped.

I want to do a VLOOKUP to find some information to compose an email. I've searched for the past day and see nothing related to this anywhere. I seem to understand how to code the VLOOKUP in Excel VBA.

I basically want to :
User enters data
lookup data on spreadsheet
obtain info from vlookup on spreadsheet
create and email with the proper recipients based on lookup

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

The vlookup function is a member of the worksheetfunction collection, which belongs to the excel application, rather than the workbook object.
Vorpal's answer above should work - they're creating a workbook, then setting the oExcel object to the parent of the workbook object, which is an instance of the excel application.

That allows you to access the worksheetfunction collection of the oExcel object, and then the vlookup method, which works the same as the vlookup function in a normal spreadsheet.

It strikes me as a somewhat roundabout way to do it, personally, I'd just create an instance of an Excel application object directly and access the worksheetfunction collection from there, rather than creating a workbook and assigning the excel application object via the .parent method, but it should still work.

Answer (score -1):

This was a call to Excel in VBScript using Office 2003 (might even have been earlier), but the solution will go something like:

```
    On Error Resume Next
      Set oWB=CreateObject("Excel.Sheet") 'it is actually a workbook
      'Works only if excel is already open
    On Error Goto 0
    If oWB Is Nothing Then
      'open the excel application -- it will be hidden
      Set oExcel=CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      oExcel.visible = true
      '''more stuff
    else
      set oExcel = oWB.Parent
```

From there you can do whatever you want with the workbook, worksheet using normal Excel vba.
Specifically, from Outlook you would call vlookup like so:

```
    oExcel.worksheetfunction.vlookup(...<br>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer here - I'm not quite sure I understand how to implement this though...I set a variable to the path of the spreadsheet, can I call that variable in this code somewhere that I don't see? It looks like this just opens Excel and hides it?